# lost file in home directory

Tags: 14.04, home-directory

After deleting shortcuts placed on desktop (`documents`, `downloads`, `pictures`, etc) I have lost all files. There is just a notification:

> Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/home/ernests/Videos': No such file or directory.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Create your folders again and use this command first:

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

After that, you can define your main folders correctly. Edit the lines for your case and save file & exit. You will see a document like that:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

If it is necessary, you can reboot your pc.

Comment: 1. There are no changes after editing "gedit". 2 . After restarting no there are no saved any changes  in"gedit". 3. I found "download" shortcut after downloading a file

Comment: Hi! First, gedit is only software for edit. you must create the folders. After this, you must edit "user-dirs.dirs" file. In this case, it should be okay. Did you like that?